# powershell: How to show only the message when throw exception?

Tags: powershell, throw

I need to throw an exception when a directory is not found and suppress the detail informations.

```
if( ! (Test-Path -Path $destDir)  )
{
    throw "Directory $destDir not found!" 
}
```

In this case the message is shown `and the details`, where it was thrown in the code.

Is there a way to show only the message without the details?

(I tested `throw ... 2>$null` but that doesn't work)

Comment: you could use `write-error` and `exit` / `break`

Comment: @Paul write-error does also show show the details. My solution is to use `write-host "directory missing" -ForegroundColor Red`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `$_.Exception.Message` in your catch block. More information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx).